# IIS Redirect Request

Tags: redirect, iis

I have a site names WebPortal configured in IIS 8:

[image]

The bindings are:

[image]

Now, I can call the site with https://portal.xxx.ch/WebPortal

Can someone help me, what I have to do, that I can call it also with https://portal.xxx.ch directly?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a redirect in the default file (index.html) in the IIS root. Adding below should work. Make sure index.html is the default file for the IIS root.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/WebPortal" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```